# How to get the integer value out of a string that might not always contain a number

Tags: python

I have a list comprehension which now contain this hillarious list comprehension below.

```
[int([y or 0 for y in ["".join(re.findall(r'[0-9*]', x))]][0]) for x in [acc['id_number']]][0]
```

The `int` function in python is not that effective.

The issue is I wish there is a cleaner way to get an integer out of the `acc['id_number']`. The code works fine.

I want to insert the data in an SQL database so I want the `acc['id_number']` to be strictly an integer.

`id_number` can be `'1234'`, `'na'`, `'gh1234'`. I want the number out of these strings and 0 where the string contains no number as in the case of `'na'`

If the `int` function worked on the strings as `'gh000'` or even `''`. This line wouldn't get that long.

```py
import re

raw_accounts = [
    {'account_name': "someone", 'id_number': "2432"},
    {'account_name': "another person", 'id_number': "na"},
    {'account_name': "some other person", 'id_number': "gh134"},
    {'account_name': "another one", 'id_number': "24124"}
]


data = [
    (
        acc['account_name'],
        [int([y or 0 for y in ["".join(re.findall(r'[0-9*]', x))]][0]) for x in [acc['id_number']]][0]
    ) for acc in raw_accounts
]

print(data)
```

Comment: The `*` needs to be put outside of the character class: `[0-9]*`.

Comment: What should be the result of int conversion of "gh1234" or "na" or maybe "123rtw456"?

Comment: @InSync try it my way and you would see that it works fine

Comment: @MichaelButscher an integer. 1234 from gh1234 and 0 from 'na'.

Comment: @surge10 ...if you want to match `*` in `foo*bar`, that is.

Comment: What is `[0` at the end supposed to be?

Comment: The line is a list comprehension. We don't need a list so we get the only value out of the list

Comment: As asked previously: what would the output of `"123rtw456"` be? `123` or `456` or `123456` or something else?

Comment: Why are you using a list comprehension if you don't want to make a list?

Comment: @001 well the id numbers I am working with will only include characters like rtw at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
data = [
    (
        acc['account_name'],
        int('0' + ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, acc['id_number']))
    ) for acc in raw_accounts
]
```

Comment: Yours is the shortest with just 71 characters.

Comment: @surge10 This shouldn't be a criterion for real programming. There is an extra site for playing code golf.

Comment: I just wanted a shorter line for my code and yours is the shortest. And please what is that extra site for playing code golf?

Comment: The site is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the list comprehension. Use a regexp to extract the integer from the string. If it doesn't match, use 0.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
data = [
    (
        acc['account_name'],
        int(match.group()) if (match := regex.search(acc['id_number'])) else 0
        
    ) for acc in raw_accounts
]
```

Comment: the for statement probably should be out of the tuple.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (match := regex.search(acc['id_number']))`?